# Why am I getting java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed?

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, resultset

Today While developing a piece of code to fetch user details from the database on execution of a stored procedure i have came across the following exception -

**Exception**

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:796)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6857)
at biz.roitech.colibri.dao.impl.MUserDaoImpl.navLinkWithSubLink(MUserDaoImpl.java:65)
at biz.roitech.colibri.ume.service.impl.LoginServiceImpl.login(LoginServiceImpl.java:61)
at biz.roitech.colibri.ume.action.LoginAction.login(LoginAction.java:263)
at biz.roitech.colibri.ume.action.LoginAction.login(LoginAction.java:92)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
at biz.roitech.colibri.interceptor.CustomI18NInterceptor.intercept(CustomI18NInterceptor.java:36)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at rt.template.startup.EntityManagerInterceptor.intercept(EntityManagerInterceptor.java:29)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at rt.template.interceptors.AuthenticationInterceptor.handleExcludedActions(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:38)
at rt.template.interceptors.AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:143)
at com.google.inject.struts2.Struts2Factory$ProvidedInterceptor.intercept(Struts2Factory.java:215)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:546)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at rt.template.startup.TemplateContextFilter.doFilter(TemplateContextFilter.java:46)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1201)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:163)
at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1201)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Code to fetch User Details from the database using procedure call

```
UserDetails userDetails;
    UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
    Set<RoleDto> roleSet = new HashSet<>();
    List<NavLinkDto> navLinkDtos = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        // em.getTransaction().begin();
        SessionImpl sessionImpl = ((SessionImpl) em.getDelegate());
        Connection cc = sessionImpl.connection();
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

        callableStatement = cc.prepareCall("{call LoginProcedure (?,?,?,?)}");
        callableStatement.setString(1, userId);
        callableStatement.setString(2, password);
        callableStatement.setString(3, ip);
        callableStatement.setString(4, locale);
        boolean isResultSet = callableStatement.execute();
        ResultSet rs1 = callableStatement.getResultSet();
        while (rs1.next()) {
            userDto = new UserDto(rs1.getInt(1), rs1.getString(2), rs1.getString(3), rs1.getString(4), rs1.getString(5), rs1.getString(6), rs1.getString(7));
            String[] roleArray = rs1.getString(8).split(",");
            for (String role : roleArray) {
                roleSet.add(new RoleDto(role));
            }
        }
        rs1.close();
        if (callableStatement.getMoreResults()) {
            ResultSet rs2 = callableStatement.getResultSet();
            while (rs2.next()) {
                NavLinkDto navlink = new NavLinkDto();
                navlink.setLinkText(rs2.getString(1));
                String[] sublinkText = rs2.getString(2).split(",");
                String[] sublinkPath = rs2.getString(3).split(",");
                List<NavSubLinkDto> subLinkList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < sublinkText.length; i++) {
                    NavSubLinkDto sublink = new NavSubLinkDto(sublinkPath[i], sublinkText[i]);
                    subLinkList.add(sublink);
                }
                navlink.setSubLinkList(subLinkList);
                navLinkDtos.add(navlink);
            }

            rs2.close();
        }
        if (callableStatement.getMoreResults()) {
            ResultSet rs3 = callableStatement.getResultSet();
            while (rs3.next()) {
                userDto.setErrorMessage(rs3.getString(1));
            }
            rs3.close();
        }
        userDetails = new UserDetails(userDto, navLinkDtos, roleSet);
    } catch (RuntimeException | SQLException re) {
        re.printStackTrace();
        throw new DaoException(re);
    }
    return userDetails;
}
```

While debugging the code the exception is thrown at the 2nd while loop where ResultSet rs2 is checked for next() and NavLinkDto navlink object is populated by navlink.setLinkText(rs2.getString(1)). The While loop executes first time as expected and populates  NavLinkDto object after that it again checks for next() and generates the exception

> Exception occurred in target VM: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed<

I don't understand why the ResultSet is getting closed inside the while loop. 
Is there any problem with the coding structure ?

Comment: Please share the complete code

Comment: Did you try with `ResultSet rs1 = callableStatement.executeQuery();` instead of executing and then getting the result set?

Comment: @BackSlash What difference does it make if I use ResultSet rs1 = callableStatement.executeQuery(); instead of callableStatement = cc.prepareCall("{call LoginProcedure (?,?,?,?)}");
        callableStatement.setString(1, userId);
        callableStatement.setString(2, password);
        callableStatement.setString(3, ip);
        callableStatement.setString(4, locale);
        boolean isResultSet = callableStatement.execute();
        ResultSet rs1 = callableStatement.getResultSet(); I think the later is more organized.

Comment: @ArindamDas Just a different form, might be worth trying. Also, you should check  `isResultSet` before doing things on the result set. If it's `false`, no result set is available. That might also be the issue you are having.

Comment: Do any of your constructors or methods called in the loop also execute something on the same connection? Does your connection pool limit the lifetime of a connection and have you exceed that time? Which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using? Which version of MySQL are you using? What is the code of your stored procedure (and try reducing your problem to a [mcve]).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am using Hibernate C3PO connection pooling and have increased the connection timeout time along with c3p0.idle_test_period. But to my suprise it didn't help. I am using mysql 5.1.19. The code in stored in procedure is to return a UserDetails .

Comment: If you are using 5.1.19 which is very old (April 2012), consider trying to upgrade your driver first. The latest 5.1.x is 5.1.47 (August 2018), and the latest overall version is 8.0.13 (October 2018). In any case, the idle_test_period setting of C3P0 is not a lifetime, it specifies how often unused connections in the pool are to be tested which does not affect connections in use. The setting I meant is called [`unreturnedConnectionTimeout`](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#unreturnedConnectionTimeout) in C3P0

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for that, I just used unreturnedConnectionTimeout in C3P0 along with debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces set to true, and it solved the ResultSet problem.

Comment: @ArindamDas: You can answer your own question (and accept that answer). I think it will be more useful for future visitors, who will immediately see the solution to your problem, rather than checking the comments...